# ValidationError: Expected a boolean primitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, boolean, text-to-speech

initial premise: I've never used a boolean and I'm a beginner developer

**code**:

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    PermissionFlagsBits,
    PermissionsBitField,
    EmbedBuilder,
  } = require("discord.js");

    const { generateDependencyReport, AudioPlayerStatus, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource  } = require('@discordjs/voice'); 
  const googleTTS = require("google-tts-api");
  const translate = require("google-translate-api-x");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName(`tts`)
    .setDescription(`Fai ripetere al bot un messaggio in un canale vocale`)
    .addStringOption((option) =>
        option
          .setName("messaggio")
          .setDescription("Scrivi il messaggio da far ripetere dal bot in vocale")
          .setRequired(true)
      )
    .addBooleanOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName("rallentatore")
      .setDescription("Vuoi che il messaggio sia mandato a rallentatore?")
      .setRequired("true")
  ),  
  async execute(interaction, client) {

    const testo = interaction.options.getString("messaggio");
    const slow = interaction.options.getBoolean("rallentatore");

     const res = await translate(`${testo}`, {to: aa});


     const url = googleTTS.getAudioUrl(testo, {
        lang: res.from.language.iso,
        slow: slow,
        host: 'https://translate.google.com',
      });

      


      const { generateDependencyReport, AudioPlayerStatus, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource  } = require('@discordjs/voice');



      const voiceChannelId = interaction.member.voice.channel.id
        const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel
        const guildId = interaction.guild.id

        
        const player = createAudioPlayer();

    

        const resource = createAudioResource(url);
        player.play(resource);

        
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannelId,
            guildId: guildId,
            adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });    



        const subscription = connection.subscribe(player);


        if (subscription) {
            setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 30_000);
        }

 
    
  },
};
```

**error**:

```js
ValidationError: Expected a boolean primitive
    at BooleanValidator.handle (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:552:71)
    at BooleanValidator.parse (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)
    at validateRequired (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:849:20)
    at SlashCommandBooleanOption.setRequired (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:962:5)
    at C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\src\commands\tools\tts.js:26:8
    at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1262:50)
    at MixedClass.addBooleanOption (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1233:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\src\commands\tools\tts.js:22:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10) {
  validator: 's.boolean',
  given: 'true'
```

I've tried everything to fix it. As I said above, I'm not a developer with skills or knowledge but I'm a beginner, I apologize if this question might be obvious or simple. It's my first time using boolean so I'm not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

```
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName(`tts`)
    .setDescription(`Fai ripetere al bot un messaggio in un canale vocale`)
    .addStringOption((option) =>
        option
          .setName("messaggio")
          .setDescription("Scrivi il messaggio da far ripetere dal bot in vocale")
          .setRequired(true)
      )
    .addBooleanOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName("rallentatore")
      .setDescription("Vuoi che il messaggio sia mandato a rallentatore?")
      .setRequired(true)
  ),
```

Try change `.setRequired("true")` to `.setRequired(true)` in your `SlashCommandBuilder`, should solve your problem.
You are sending a **"string"** instead of an actual **boolean**.